# How to assign range(10) to a ndarray which shape is (10, 1) conveniently in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.empty((1, 10, 1), np.int8)
a[0] = range(10)
```

It throw error: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10) into shape (10,1)`

Comment: First I thought this should be flagged as a duplicate. But then I could not find a concise question/answer pair that matched this question so I wrote one :)

Comment: @kazemakase Yeah, I can not find the common question cover this question so I have to ask.

Comment: In assignment as in other broadcasting, it can add dimensions on the left, but you have to add them on right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options that work in this case:

```
a[0, :, 0] = np.arange(10)  # assign to 1D slice

a[0].flat = range(10)  # assign to flattened 2D slice

a[0] = np.arange(10).reshape(10, 1)  # bring the rigth side into correct shape

a[0] = np.arange(10)[:, np.newaxis]  # bring the rigth side into correct shape
```

Note the use of `np.arange` instead of `range`. The former directly creates an ndarray with a sequence of values, while the latter creates an iterable that needs to be converted into an array for the assignment.

In the case of assigning to `flat` it makes sense to use `range` because both are iterators.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `a[0, :, 0] = range(10)`.